# publishing website with quarto in Rstudio

Tags: github, rstudio, quarto

I am following instructions [here](https://quarto.org/docs/publishing/github-pages.html) and trying to publish a website developed with quarto in Rstudio. I used Build tab -> Render Website and then use terminal with `quarto publish gh-pages`. It all goes smoothly until it is stuck at

`Deploying gh-pages branch to website (this may take a few minutes)`

And then it just goes for hours and just hangs... Quarto is the newest version, just installed. How do i publish it on gitpages! Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has answered this, I'll explain how I fixed it. I'm not sure why this works, but it appears something is stuck behind the scenes when the `gh-pages` branch is created.

First,

```bash
git clean -df
```

to remove whatever weird stuff might be clogging your repo. Note that my `.gitignore` already ignores the project `output-dir`, so you may need to delete that directory manually otherwise. Anyway, just get rid of everything that the render makes.

Then

```bash
git worktree prune
```

to release yourself from the shadow `gh-pages` branch.

Now you can just `quarto publish gh-render` like you wanted and it should work.